# string matching and highligting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add text highlighting feature to my website. Im using javascript. It works fine when the string that I am trying to match is in single line. But it doesnt when Im trying a sentence that is long and has two or more lines. Ive an example specified in jsfidde. What could be the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/21/

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/23/). Also, check out word boundaries `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

The example works fine. There's only one instance of the string *another financials-led crisis* in the text. If you change `$('#entity').html()` to *crisis*, 2 instances of that string are highlighted in `$('#article')`. If you wanted to highlight *another financials-led crisis* everywhere (so, also within `$('#entity')`), try surrounding it with a `div#container` [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/ehzPQ/26/)

Comment: the link you ve provided is nt wrking

Comment: whats the change that uve made"?

Comment: inserting it inside a div container wont work as I cnt use that solution inside my website as these two contents are in two different part...thats not a proper solution..